# How to convert a json object into a dataframe when arrays are of different lengths?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

I am trying to convert a json format into a dataframe but getting an error saying "All arrays must be of the same length".
Below is the code. Any advice are highly appreciated.

I have the following codes

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
from pandas import json_normalize

resp = requests.get("https://unstats.un.org/SDGAPI/v1/sdg/Indicator/Data?indicator=7.2.1")

resp.json()

pd.DataFrame(resp.json())
ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to convert the entire json using Pandas [from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) and [transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) (T) methods:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

resp = requests.get(
    "https://unstats.un.org/SDGAPI/v1/sdg/Indicator/Data?indicator=7.2.1"
)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(resp.json(), orient="index").T
```

```py
print(df.info())
# Output
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column         Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------         --------------  -----
 0   size           1 non-null      object
 1   totalElements  1 non-null      object
 2   totalPages     1 non-null      object
 3   pageNumber     1 non-null      object
 4   attributes     1 non-null      object
 5   dimensions     1 non-null      object
 6   data           1 non-null      object
dtypes: object(7)
memory usage: 184.0+ bytes
```

But if you are interested in specific values of your json, which, I presume, are the ones associated with the key `data`, then simply do:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(resp.json()["data"])

print(df.info())
# Output
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 25 entries, 0 to 24
Data columns (total 21 columns):
 #   Column             Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------             --------------  -----  
 0   goal               25 non-null     object 
 1   target             25 non-null     object 
 2   indicator          25 non-null     object 
 3   series             25 non-null     object 
 4   seriesDescription  25 non-null     object 
 5   seriesCount        25 non-null     object 
 6   geoAreaCode        25 non-null     object 
 7   geoAreaName        25 non-null     object 
 8   timePeriodStart    25 non-null     float64
 9   value              25 non-null     object 
 10  valueType          25 non-null     object 
 11  time_detail        0 non-null      object 
 12  timeCoverage       0 non-null      object 
 13  upperBound         0 non-null      object 
 14  lowerBound         0 non-null      object 
 15  basePeriod         0 non-null      object 
 16  source             25 non-null     object 
 17  geoInfoUrl         0 non-null      object 
 18  footnotes          25 non-null     object 
 19  attributes         25 non-null     object 
 20  dimensions         25 non-null     object 
dtypes: float64(1), object(20)
memory usage: 4.2+ KB
```

Comment: Thanks Laurent for your solution. Can I understand that in order to use json.loads, I have to convert the whole dictionary (from real.json)  into a string ?

Comment: Hi, no, it was just to illustrate the error with a simple use case. I have updated my answer to get to the point. Cheers.